# How to divide sum by 2 if checkbox checked? javascript/html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sum, division

Like written in the Title. I am trying to get the sum from some fields - this is working fine already. But I want to add a function that if the check box is checked  before and I press the "Calculate" Button the sum should be divided / 2 automatically. I don't have the code I already have in the moment but if its needed I will upload later. But for now maybe its some easy thing and very general. Maybe someone can give some example already. kind regards

Comment: you will have to share your markup and existing code to show us how the sum is calculated

Comment: Psuedo: `if check box checked: sum = accumulator/2` you can get the checkbox change by using `onChange` and use either jquery or bog standard JS to get the state. eg `if(document.getElementById('xxx').checked)` or `$(xxx).is(':checked')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#calculateButton').on('click', function(){
  // do summation and assign it to sum variable
  var sum = sumCalculation();
  if ($('#checkbox').is(':checked'))
  {
    sum = sum/2;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide any markup, you should do something like this, but adapted to your code:

```
var sum = calculateSum();

if ($("#checkbox").is(':checked')) sum = sum/2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
$("#checkbox").change(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    // do the division
  }
});
```

Assuming your checkbox would have id="checkbox"

Answer (score 0):

```
var chksum = document.getElementById('u r checkbox ID').checked;

if(chksum=="true")
{
sum=sum/2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this. Note let the id of checkbox is #checkbox**

```
var sum = 10;
$("#checkbox").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        sum /=2;
    }
    alert(sum);
});
```